# Preallocating Data.Vector for O(1) in GHC?

Tags: haskell, memory, optimization

In C++ world there is an optimisation for `std::vector` when `push_back`'ing known amount of items  to new vector - [preallocate space](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/)

Is there analogue for Haskell unboxed vectors? Doc says `cons` is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Data.Vector.(++)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.9.1/docs/Data-Vector.html) is O(m+n) according to the docs, which is more efficient than `cons`-ing n times. So if you just put the new elements in a new vector, you can append that to the old one efficiently.

Note that in C++ you might do this in only O(n) provided you have enough preallocated area. The extra O(m) you get in Haskell, I guess, is due to Data.Vector being immutable, and requiring a copy.

If you want to use mutable vectors instead, have a look to 

[`Data.Vector.Mutable.grow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.9.1/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html#v:grow).